# My virtual machines cannot connect to the network

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I am a beginner at cyber security. I installed Kioptrix Level 1 and My Tomcat Host on VMWare 17. However when I start the virtual machines they don't seem to connect. I also have a Kali Linux installed virtual machine which work perfectly fine so far; and when I run netdiscover -i eth0, I can't see them on the list. All virtual machines were working a few days ago so I don't know what changed. For now, kioptrix starts normally but doesn't appear on the list and Tomcat host gives the following error: [ 41.500861] systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online. [ 41.778881] systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking. Also naturally doesn't appear on the list too. I started learning cyber security just a week ago and everything was working fine at first. I don't know what might have caused the change. Note that I checked that all machines are connected in bridged mode. I also cannot use the terminal to restart Network Manager.

I deleted the virtual machines and installed them again. I even completely removed the files in case they are corrupted, and downloaded them again but they still don't work. I searched for the problem online and as far as I understand, My Tomcat Host problem is likely caused by a timeout of Network Manager but didn't understand the problem completely.

Because I am inexperienced, I don't know what information to provide so please ask anything about the situation if missing.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Make sure you have a backup of the machines. Uninstall VMware V17, restart, then install Vmware V17 and test. (I use VMware).

Comment: I don't know VMware. Somewhere in the virtual machine settings there's a page about networking. How is it set up?

Comment: The question says machine are on Bridged Networking which should work fine. It does work fine here.

Comment: how does your network assign IPs?  Router, direct from the ISP modem?  If you've got an automated method (and available IPs) for IP assignment, your VMs should get one,  Make sure you have the correct NIC selected in your network settings also